# Unable to display multiple uploaded images in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to upload multiple images onto my webpage but I'm having trouble understanding how to get a valid URL for the source of the image and to check if the number of files uploaded is correct. How should I go about doing so? Here is a sample of the code I have written:

```
<div id = "image_display">
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" multiple>
</div>
```

```
const img = document.getElementById('image');
const display = document.getElementById('image_display');

img.onchange = evt =>{
    const [file] = img.files;
    if(file){
        const newImg = document.createElement('img',{
            src : URL.createObjectURL(file)
        })
        display.appendChild(newImg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break-up the creation of the image.

0. use `document.createElement` to create the image
1. set the new image's src

   ```
    const newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.src = URL.createObjectURL( file );
   ```